# Is it safe store a username inside a cookie?

Tags: angularjs, security, cookies

I working on security and I 'm storing a session key inside a cookie. I will use it to check if the user is actually connected and if he didn't tried to change some info.

at first I think to just check if the session key is inside the database, but I think it would be more secured to check if the current user has the session key instead of just finding a user that have that key and assume that he must be the one connected.

I know I should use session storage, but since I'm using AngularJS, I don't know how to achieve that, so no need to point out that I should use session instead.

-Would it be safe to put the username inside the cookie?
-Would just using the session key and assume that the user that got the key most be the connected one be a good idea (it would simplify some of my request to the database later on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like essentially what you are trying to achieve by storing the username in a cookie is to make the username a 2nd factor in a 2-factor authentication scheme. The problem is, the username always travels in a cookie alongside the session id and so when one is exposed, the other is too. So no security is gained.

Furthermore, there is no valid security argument to storing username in a client cookie and then trusting that this username is the same one associated with a session. The client can trivially change the value of the cookie before submitting a request. And any attacker that has already managed to have sniffed out the session id from a cookie could probably just have easily read the username cookie too, making a session hijack attack practically the same difficulty. At best, you've achieved no higher security and added unnecessary complexity to your code. At worst, you've betrayed usernames which wouldn't have otherwise have been visible to an attacker. eg. in the case of expired sessions.

OWASP Recommendation:

> ### Session ID Content (or Value)
>
> The session ID content (or value) must be meaningless to prevent information disclosure attacks, where an attacker is able to decode the contents of the ID and extract details of the user, the session, or the inner workings of the web application.
>
> The session ID must simply be an identifier on the client side, and its value must never include sensitive information (or PII). The meaning and business or application logic associated to the session ID must be stored on the server side, and specifically, in session objects or in a session management database or repository. The stored information can include the client IP address, User-Agent, e-mail, username, user ID, role, privilege level, access rights, language preferences, account ID, current state, last login, session timeouts, and other internal session details. If the session objects and properties contain sensitive information, such as credit card numbers, it is required to duly encrypt and protect the session management repository.
>
> It is recommended to create cryptographically strong session IDs through the usage of cryptographic hash functions such as SHA1 (160 bits).

-- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Content_.28or_Value.29

Comment: I know, but that's why I get the session_key. If someone try to just change the username, it won't work since the session key won't fit with the wright username.

Comment: @KévinDuguay If you retrieve the username from the database then there isn't even a reason to compare it, so why store it at all in the cookie ?

Comment: @KévinDuguay What do you gain by doing that? The session was presumably already linked to a user on the server side and not transferrable to another user.

Comment: It's just that if I don't store the username, well I need to check throw all my user table to try to find the session_key to check if the user is connected. SO I tought that it might be better to have to username to so that when I do a request, I can just find the une entry of the user and check his session key insted of having to go throw aaaaaaaaaaaaaall the users.

Comment: @Asaph What the you mean by: "The session was presumably already linked to a user on the server side and not transferrable to another user"

Comment: @KévinDuguay The session id needs to be nothing more than secret token that can be used to look up more information *on the server side*. OWASP is a good reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Content_.28or_Value.29

Comment: @Asaph Is what I'm doing (generating a random hashed session key), a good idea? Would my session key make a good secret token?

Comment: @KévinDuguay That would highly depend on whether your random number generator is cryptographically secure. If an attacker can initiate a session, and then based on their session id, predict the next pseudo-random number in the sequence, they can hijack the next session created. Be very careful as many programming languages offer both flavors of random number generators. ie. `java.util.Random` and `java.security.SecureRandom` in java. PHP has a handful of difference random number generators. Be careful which one you choose.

Comment: There are many subtle ways to mess up web security. If you are going to build this layer yourself, rather than using an existing piece of software, I suggest going through the entire [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) to give yourself some measure of confidence that you haven't overlooked anything.

Comment: I have a API to access the DB, so I plain using php in the API to generate a long random string, than us password_hash . Someone have a suggestion of what I should use to generate the long random string?

Comment: @KévinDuguay Which php function do you use to generate a random number? [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand) is not cryptographically secure. See the caution note on the [doc page for `rand()`](http://php.net/rand). Also, please create a new question for this topic. This discussion is getting too long.